# Setting an SQL Query AS a variable or parameter (Integer prefered) and using it

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables, parameters, parameter-passing

I couldn't solve that mistery question in **SQL SERVER**.

Here an example that I tried to do and it didn't work.

```
DECLARE @Total int;
SET @Total = (SELECT COUNT(*)-10 FROM MYTABLE)

SELECT TOP @Total IdColumn FROM MYTABLE
```

How can I use the following query

SELECT COUNT(*)-10 FROM MYTABLE

as an integer variable, somewhere else in my code.

Comment: Depending on how MYTABLE is set up you may want to include ordering in the query so you can be sure you're getting the results you expect.

Answer (score 5):

When you use a variable in a top clause, you need to use parenthesis, like this:

SELECT TOP (@Total) IdColumn FROM MYTABLE

If you are using SQL2000, you cannot use a variable in a top clause.  If you try, you will get a parse/syntax error.  Instead, you can use RowCount, like this:

```
DECLARE @Total int;
SET @Total = (SELECT COUNT(*)-10 FROM MYTABLE)

Set RowCount @Total
SELECT IdColumn FROM MYTABLE
Set RowCount 0
```

Comment: Just tested and it works... no freaking way... I've missed this all this time... /me fails. +1 :D

Comment: I just updated my answer to include SQL2000 functionality.  You should probably have mentioned the version of SQL Server you are using in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Use Brackets: The following works for me:

```
DECLARE @Total int;
SET @Total = (SELECT COUNT(*)-10 FROM MYTABLE)

SELECT TOP (@Total) IdColumn FROM MYTABLE
```

Comment: Line 4: Incorrect syntax near '(' 

Exactly the same things I wrote.

Comment: Yes you are right: This only works for SQLServer 2003 and up.